# How do I merge all package.json files from each git submodule into one package.json file?

Tags: node.js, git

I have different submodules inside a main repository. I want to merge all the package.json file for each submodule into one package.json file in the main repo. How can I do that using node.js?

I want to use the npm package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-merge

but that requires me to read from the submodules using node. How can I read from each submodule (get a list) using node and merge the package.json files?

note that I have submodules within submodules.

for example, I can have submodule test. and I can have submodule render within test